# Artemis ActiveMQ can't connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, activemq-artemis

Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
Artemis ActiveMQ 2.4.0(localhost)
PGADMIN(docker)+postgres(docker)
I can to connect to base through pgadmin, but artemis can't
I want to connect Artemis to my base for store pages, but in start, ia have a trouble:

```
2018-04-24 14:57:58,534 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,jdbcDriverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver,jdbcConnectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user=super&password=super,messageTableName=MESSAGE_TABLE,bindingsTableName=BINDINGS_TABLE,largeMessageTableName=LARGE_MESSAGES_TABLE,pageStoreTableName=PAGES_TABLE,)
2018-04-24 14:57:58,566 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum name size for the page store table prefix is 10 characters: THE PAGING STORE CAN'T START
```

There is my config:
broker.xml

```
      <store>
     <database-store>
        <jdbc-connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.20.173:5432/postgres?user=super&amp;password=super</jdbc-connection-url>
        <page-store-table-name>PAGES_TABLE</page-store-table-name>
        <bindings-table-name>BINDINGS_TABLE</bindings-table-name>
        <message-table-name>MESSAGE_TABLE</message-table-name>
        <large-message-table-name>LARGE_MESSAGES_TABLE</large-message-table-name>
        <jdbc-driver-class-name>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbc-driver-class-name>
     </database-store>
  </store>
```

By default, Artemis will store all pages to local directories, not in base

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As others (e.g., Justin) has already mentioned, it seems a misalignment between code and code comments, but luckly the related JIRA reports a more explicit description that explain that limit:

> ARTEMIS-1084
>   Oracle12C has table name size limit of 30 chars. When using paging and a table name of >10 chars. Artemis will work fine, until it's Page UUID size goes above 20 chars. Then start failing to page.

In summary, the complete page table names are given by:

```
page-store-table-name + UUID binary encoded form
```

And Oracle 12c allows just a total of 30 chars for a table name, that means:

```
page-store-table-name <= 30 - UUID binary encoded form length
```

with UUID binary encoded form `length = 16 + 4 (the '-' char) = 20` bytes. That is:

```
page-store-table-name <= 10 chars
```

The problem I see is that such limit shouldn't be enforce for any DBMS, but just for oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant error message describes the problem:

```
The maximum name size for the page store table prefix is 10 characters
```

Looking at the code, the "page store table prefix" here is based on the broker's configuration. In your case, you're using:

```
PAGES_TABLE
```

Which is 11 characters. The default value here is:

```
PAGE_TABLE
```

Which is 10 characters. If you use a a value here which is 10 characters or less then I would expect the error to go away.

The issue here is that some RDBMS (e.g. Oracle) can only support table names up to 30 characters and the `page-store-table-name` is actually just a prefix for tables that will have an additional 20-character UUID appended to their name. Therefore the `page-store-table-name` has to be 10 characters or less to account for the UUID and still remain under the 30 character limit.